# How to respond server-side to routes using Meteor and Iron-Router?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm sending a file from client-side to server side using XHR:

```
$(document).on('drop', function(dropEvent) {
    dropEvent.preventDefault();
    _.each(dropEvent.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files, function(file) {
        // ...
        xhr.open('POST', Router.routes['upload'].path(), true);
        xhr.send(file);
    });
})
```

Now I want to respond to this POST server-side and save the file to disk. [The docs](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) only seems to talk about handling things client-side; I don't even know how to get a hook on the server-side.

All I have for routes right now is this:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('home', {
        path: '/'
    });

    this.route('upload', {
        path: '/upload',
        action: function() {
            console.log('I never fire');
        }
    });
});
```

With [connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/), I could do:

```
Connect.middleware.router(function(route) {
    route.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
        // my server-side code here
    });
});
```

Is there anything similar for [Iron-Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router)?

---

Digging through the internals, I discovered Meteor is using `connect` under the hood, and I can do something like this:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.method === 'POST' && req.url === '/upload') {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end();
    } else next();
});
```

But I have no idea how to get the user in this context.

Comment: Just noted [this comment](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/wiki#server-side-routing). Maybe it's not even implemented.....what are some alternatives to Iron Router then?

Answer (score 5):

By default, your routes are created as client side routes. This means, a link to that route will be handled in the browser vs. making a server request. But you can also create server side routes by providing a `where` option to the route. The handler for the server side route exposes the `request`, `response`, and `next` properties of the `Connect` object. The syntax has changed a little from 0.5.4 to the dev branch so I'll provide both examples depending on which you're using:

**v0.5.4**

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('upload', {
    where: 'server',
    handler: function () {
      var request = this.request;
      var response = this.response;
      // do whatever
    }
  });
});
```

**dev**

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('upload', {
    where: 'server',
    action: function () {
      var request = this.request;
      var response = this.response;
      // do whatever
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Can I get the [Meteor user](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_user) within that context? And access the database?

Comment: The Meteor user won't be set because you're not dealing at the DDP level anymore. I haven't gotten to thinking about a good way to do that. Probably something I'll walk with the Core team about. In the mean time, for file uploading I've been using DDP for that using the meteor-file package: https://github.com/EventedMind/meteor-file. Requires HTML5 File API on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload file with use of EJSON and normal meteor "methods" this way you will be able to get access to user data because it is visible only inside methods and publish functions on server side

this video tutorial may be a [good start](https://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-build-a-file-upload-package)

also package [CollectionFS](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/collectionFS) provides some upload functionalities. It is now little outdated, but idea stays the same.

Comment: Do either of these solutions allow you to get the upload progress? With XHR I can have a progress bar; last time I looked at the meteor methods, it tries to do the whole thing in one big chunk, unless that's been updated. Edit: collectionFS sounds like it does. Even for downloads... neat!

Answer (score 1):

The same people who brought you iron-router also have [meteor-file](https://github.com/EventedMind/meteor-file) which will do the file transfer for you, or you can use as an example for your own implementation

Answer (score 0):

[Meteor Router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router) (now deprecated) has server side routing support:

```
Meteor.Router.add('/upload', 'POST', function() {
  // do stuff
});
```

Comment: You cannot use router and iron router in one project - or rather, it's not that simple.

Comment: Yes you cannot but there was a question about Iron Router alternatives.

Comment: Why not? I'm using them both in one project and I didn't have to do anything special. I'm using Iron Router for client-side routing and Meteor Router for server-side.

Comment: We also use both. We're moving away from Meteor Router though.