# upload image from local computer and saving them to a folder with redactor in meteorjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteorite, redactor

I am using redactor plugin with meteorjs, to format the texts and add images, videos and links.Redactor supports uploading images as a web link, but here I wanted to add a button to upload images from local machine. For this I have added the button to the redactor. It is showing the browse image selection and is working.

```
   $('.editor').redactor({
    imageUpload:"/upload",

    imageUploadCallback: function(image, json)
    {
        console.log(image);
        console.log(json);

    },
    imageUploadErrorCallback: function(json)
    {
        console.log(json.error);
    }
    });
```

When I print `console.log("#redactor_file").val());` it gives the name of the file. But, when I do `console.log(console.log(html);)` its gives `<p><img src="undefined"></p>`. Can I get the link or the url of the image here. If yes then how?

```
HTTP.methods({
'upload': function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    return JSON.stringify( {'data':"data"})
}
});
```

When I do `console.log(data)` using the above code it shows me Image in String format. Now I want to store the Image using GridFS. Or is there any better way to store Image in MongoDB. If yes then tell me or guide me to store image using GridFS ?

Answer (score 1):

While Redactor provides a client-side method for uploading files, [it does not provide a  server-side method](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/images/) for receipt of uploaded files. Also, stock Meteor doesn't provide such a method either.

So you have a few choices. First is through using a router such as [Iron Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router), which you could create a server-side /uploads route, and Iron Router gives you access to the request, response objects. Which might work, but because this is no longer over DDP, you don't have access to Meteor.userId, etc. See [How to respond server-side to routes using Meteor and Iron-Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544474/how-to-respond-server-side-to-routes-using-meteor-iron-router)

A more Meteor-like way of doing the file upload is [Meteor File](https://github.com/EventedMind/meteor-file) or [CollectionFS](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS) though I'm not sure how simply these would integrate with Redactor. You could definitely get them to work together, just off the top of my head I don't know how easy it would be.

Comment: Thanx for giving some valuable ideas Emgee. let me go thorough all these and see which one can do my work

Comment: For this task i was trying to use Http.methods which is called on when i select a file. but I am not getting how can i get the attributes of `<input type=file></input>`

Comment: The Meteor Http.call and related methods are for sending HTTP GET/POST requests, not for receiving them.

Comment: Can't we get the attributes of the uploaded files on clicnt side and send that to the server to store that image name and url in database?

Comment: Emgee , I analyse that redactor directly call a method defined at server side when a file or image is chosen using file input. And it is sending the image at server side which is printing when i do console.log