# How to insert object into meteor collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am just starting to learn Meteorjs and have more questions than answers.

I want to store translations for my app into a temporary Collection, and subscribe Iron Router to its publishing. I have a dictionary-object that I want to insert into the Collection.

Here is the way I do it:

In *server/translations.js*

```
translations = {
  ru_RU: {
    'value1': 'translation1',
    'value2': 'translation2'
  },

  en_US: {
    'value1': 'translation1',
    'value2': 'translation2'
  }
};
```

In *collections/translates.js*

```
Translates = new Meteor.Collection('translations');
Translates.insert(translations);
```

In *server/publications.js*

```
Meteor.publish('translations', function (lang) { //<-- how to pass arguments?
    return Translations.find({'translations': lang});
});
```

In *router.js*

```
//use iron-router
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'main',
    notFoundTemplate: 'not-found',
    waitOn: function () { //waiting while data received and starting router job
        return Meteor.subscribe('translations');//<-- how can i use this data?
    }
});
```

How can I use these Objects client-side?

Comment: Have you considered using something such as i18next ? It solves internationalization issues and provides many helpers. http://i18next.com/

Comment: I now about this package, but want to understand how to pass data from server to client synchronously

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few client/server placement issues it seems like you're working through here too, but let's focus on your question and narrow down the problem.

**Define Your Collection**

```
Translations = new Meteor.Collection('translations');
```

**Bootstrap DB Data**

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    if (Translations.find({}).count() === 0) {
        Translations.insert({
            'translation' : 'ru_RU',
            'value1': 'translation1',
            'value2': 'translation2'
        });
        Translations.insert({
            'translation': 'en_US',
            'value1': 'translation1',
            'value2': 'translation2'
        });
    }
}
```

**Publish**

If you publish a collection with an argument

```
Meteor.publish('translations', function (lang) { //lang argument
    return Translations.find({'translation': lang});
});
```

**Subscribe**

You can subscribe with the argument like this

```
Meteor.subscribe('translations', 'ru_RU'); // pass in the other language code
```

For the sake of simplicity I'll leave out iron-router, since there's a few things you have to do to setup ({{yield}} in your main template and the Router.map -- [Iron Router Quickstart](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#quick-start))

**Template Helper**

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    translations: function() {
        // return all subscribed translations
        return Translations.findOne({});
    }
});
```

**Template**

```
<template name='myTemplate'>
    {{translations.value1}}<br>
    {{translations.value2}}
</template>
```

Comment: Why Translation.found({}).count() on server equals 2, and on client 0?

Comment: I had a bug in the above code -- in publish 'Translations.find' was looking for 'translations' instead of translation' field. When it's working correctly you should see 2 on the server and 1 on the client. Subscriptions narrow down the amount of data you need to send to the client (useful for performance and data isolation)

Comment: It works, but I still have a question. I put a console.log('translate...') into helpers.translations() and it outputs two times, e.g. helper calls two times. Why is this happening?

Comment: And can you edit please `return Translations.find({})` on `return Translations.findOne({})` into the translations helper?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about the console log getting called twice -- but  its possible that the helper gets instantiated when the Template get's rendered. And parts of the template get rendered when the subscribed data changes. (also made the edits)

Comment: Tell me please how to update records in Translations collection, when object will be updated?

Comment: Take a look at the Meteor collection update docs http://docs.meteor.com/#update  - you could use the $set operator to modify a given 'value' http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set

Answer (score 0):

There are two core points to understand here:

1. The `Translates` collection exists on the Client as well.
2. Subscribing to a source makes *all* the documents published by it available on the client: irrespective of which collection they belong to. You can even return an array of cursors to publish from more than one collection.

---

Apart from that, there are a few issues with the you queries and data model.

With your definition of `translations` variable, the query `Translations.find({'translations': lang});` is not going to find anything since it will try to look for documents where a field `translation` equals the passed object. That is probably not what you want.

I would suggest making your `translation` variable hold the following data:

```
translations = [
  {
    'translation' : 'ru_RU',
    'value1': 'translation1',
    'value2': 'translation2'
  },
  {
    'translation': 'en_US',
    'value1': 'translation1',
    'value2': 'translation2'
  }
];
```

Then your query is likely to return what you want.

Another suggestion is that `Translates.insert(translations);` is going to enter an object into the table each time the server runs. That is also probably not what you want (perhaps you are not doing that on the actual client). The way to address it is by checking whether the collection is empty at the start:

```
if (Translation.find({}).count() === 0) Translation.insert(translations);
```

Finally, while subscribing, you can pass in the variables to the `subscribe` function:

```
waitOn: function () {
    return Meteor.subscribe('translations', 
                              /* user preference here */
                             this.params.userLanguagePreference
                           );
}
```

Finally, to access the collection on the client, just use `Translation.find({})` and you will get a cursor which will iterate over all the documents which have been published for your subscriptions for the client.

Comment: Now I changed translations object to array, as you advised, but cursor still returns an error, when I try fetch data.
Publication looks:
`Meteor.publish('translations', function (param) {
    return Translations.findOne({translation: param});
});`
And subscription: 
`waitOn: function () {
    var cursor = Meteor.subscribe('translations', 'ru_RU');
    cursor.fetch();
    return;
}
`
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'fetch'

Comment: @VitaliiDelVorobioff `Meteor.subscribe` does not return a Cursor,, it returns a [`Subscription` object](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe) which has only `stop` and `ready` functions. When you need the data (say, in the [`data` field](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#data) of the _route_), then you can use `Translations.find()` to get the cursor.

Comment: Store object into collection is not I want. Eventually my goal is to pass any data from server to client synchronously. How to do this, I can't understand. Does Meteor don't provide such functionality?

Comment: @VitaliiDelVorobioff You can build a [REST interface on top of Metoer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544474/how-to-respond-server-side-to-routes-using-meteor-and-iron-router) but I have not found it to be particularly useful. I prefer to communicate between the server and the client using Collections.

Comment: But this way isn't flexible. What if you want to send some json-data?

Comment: @VitaliiDelVorobioff Why is this inflexible? You can also have a look at the [Assets package](http://docs.meteor.com/#assets).