# How to add a form to meteor and react application

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I've asked similar questions (with code) to this a few times but no responses.

So I'm having alot of trouble creating a form that has elements such as `title`, `categories`, `location`, `description`, etc. and nowhere online can I find anything that suits my application.

I would like to use `state` and `props` for my form input fields and then provide insert, update and delete methods to insert a new document to `mongodb`.

These methods would be best located in `mycollection.js` file. But I don't know where to start with them, and how to link them up to my submitform (e.g. `employeeComponent.js`) component.

So, can anyone give me some insight? A link to a blog post, tutorial that I don't know of would be great, because I've done alot of research on this and maybe because it's so simple to others, nobody writes about it.

Sorry for the long question, but links to articles would be great or general advice. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's not a complete answer but you don't provide a lot of things too...

Firstly maybe this link will help you [How to insert object into meteor collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087478/how-to-insert-object-into-meteor-collection)

Then you need something like this for example:

`mycollection.js`-> content ->

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
export const MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection('myCollection');
```

`myTemplate.js`-> content ->

```
import {
    MyCollection
} from '/both/collections/mycollection.js';

Template.myTemplateName.events({
`click .state`: function(e){
     MyCollection.upsert({
       idArticle: e.idArticle
       }, {
       state: e.text()
     })
}}
```

And if it's your first time using Meteor you should take the time to do some tutorials like https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app

Comment: Hey, this is a great answer. Doesn't upsetting provide insert and updates with the one function? Thank you

Comment: You can find all the methods here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-collection/